# PHP: Handling Dynamic File Request

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, dynamic

I'm developing a Web Application where the all the image requests are to be handled by the `index.php` page directly. For example, if a request is made for file `image1.png`, it is to be redirected to `index.php`, where the details of the `image1.png` file are displayed.

I've written code for displaying the details of a file, when the filename is passed as a GET parameter to `index.php` file.

But I'm not sure how to capture all the image file requests and redirect them to `index.php`, and at the same time, pass the requested filename as a parameter via GET.

Any help would be greatful. :)

Comment: can you edit post and display your code ?

Comment: To be honest, I've no idea how to handle dynamic requests :(

Comment: what you exactly mean by dynamic request?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Any direct file request other than `.php` should be redirected to 'index.php' with filename as its parameter.

Comment: can you post your code or example ? so we will provide you a good answer for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in the .htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+\.png)$ index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

This *internally rewrites* all `.png` files to `index.php` passing the full URL as a URL parameter. (Although this notably excludes the slash prefix. You can manually include this if required. eg. `?file=/$1`.)

To extend this to include `.jpg` files as well then change the `RewriteRule` pattern:

```
RewriteRule (.+\.(png|jpg))$ index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

---

**EDIT:** To route all non-PHP files you can do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule !\.php$ index.php?file=%1 [L]
```

For all non-PHP files (note the *negated* regex with a `!` prefix), the request is rewritten, passing the requested URL to `index.php`. Note that a negated regex cannot include a capturing group, hence the requirement for a separate condition.

Note that this includes the slash prefix (since it is included as part of the `REQUEST_URI` variable), whereas the examples above did not.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked, but can I redirect all non-php file requests in the same way?

Comment: Not quite the same way, since "all non-php" files requires a negated regex - I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Just updated/fixed the `RewriteCond` to include parentheses (a capturing group) around the _CondPattern_.

Comment: An alternative is to simply rewrite to `index.php` instead of `index.php?file=%1`. Then, in your PHP you can get the requested (non-PHP) URL from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI`]` superglobal instead of your URL parameter.

Comment: that's great, but Is there any performance difference between the two methods?